# How to remove time from date?

Tags: apex, date, format

The following code returns the time of the current date:

```
System.debug('Current date: ' + Date.today().toStartOfMonth());
```

Output:

> 2018-08-01 00:00:00

**How to remove time from date?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the format method solve the issue.

```
System.debug('Current date: ' + Date.today().toStartOfMonth().format());
```

Output:

> 1-8-2018

Comment: format function returns the date in current timezone

Answer (score 7):

only way I found is to keep the date format and remove the 00 from end

```
System.debug('Current date: ' + String.valueOf(Date.today()).removeEnd(' 00:00:00'));
```

Answer (score 3):

`Date.format()` method returns the Date as a string using the locale of the context user

or if you need it in a specific format regardless User locale use something like `Datetime.format('yyyy-MM-dd')` or `Datetime.format('yyyy-MM-dd', 'America/New_York')`

e.g.

```
Date d = Date.today().toStartOfMonth();
System.debug( Datetime.newInstance(d.year(), d.month(), d.day()).format('yyy-MM-dd') );
```

Answer (score 1):

A more elegant way I found was:

`System.debug('Current date: ' + String.valueOf(Date.today().toStartOfMonth()).split(' ')[0]);`

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Your contribution is most welcome; and while your answer may well work, I would have to argue that it is no more elegant than `String.valueOf(Date.today()).removeEnd(' 00:00:00')`. :)